# Why does changing parameters inside map async loop only works on first async function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand why the following results happen. I bet there's something to do with the event loop and the fact that all sync code runs before async code, but I cannot apply that knowledge to this example.

```js
// const axios = require('axios');
const array = [1, 2, 3];

const user = {};

const promises = array.map(async (item) => {
  console.log('start');
  user['id'] = item;
  const responseUser = await axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${user.id}`
  );
  console.log('middle');
  const responseUser2 = await axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${user.id}`
  );
  console.log('end result 2: ', responseUser2.data.id);
  console.log('end result: ', responseUser.data.id);
});

Promise.all(promises);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.21.4/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Results:

```
start
start
start
middle
middle
middle
end result 2: 3
end result: 3
end result 2: 3
end result: 2
end result 2: 3
end result: 1
```

Comment: All of those promises are going to run as fast as they can in ***parallel***. You cannot share `user` and mutate it this way without some kind of mutex or lock because it produces a race condition.

Comment: @zero298 JavaScript programs are single-threaded: and in NodeJS and in the browser (at least) concurrently executing async `Promises` don't run JavaScript in parallel (though if they run internal host code, like for network IO, then _that_ code in the host could run in parallel, but JS code itself will not). So you don't need any kind of _locking_ to be thread-safe - though in this case, yes, mutating `user['id']` is wrong, but it isn't a race-condition (specifically) in this context.

Comment: You need to add an `await` to `Promise.all(promises);`, so change your code to `await Promise.all(promises);`

Comment: What did you intend to happen with the `user` variable? How did you intend to use it after all the HTTP requests had completed? Which URLs did you actually want to run (all 6 of them)?

Comment: Why are you even using `map` without a `return`? Use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Dai the term race condition is not limited to muli-threading. JavaScript engines are event driven and `await`/`async` behaves similar to cooperative multitasking. So as soon as you use `await` (or callbacks) the sequence and timing of the execution can change, and that can lead to race conditions. (For sure not that variables are modified by to cores at the same moment, but that’s not the requirement for a race condition)

Comment: @Morgan, with map you can run those request in parallel. With a traditional for loop, you can't (you could, but it would be awful to write).

Comment: @trincot, I actually am not going to use that "user" variable, but that code was written by one of my colleagues and I was trying to understand the reason why it did not work (even though it could be written differently).

Comment: @MuriloBotelho you can parallelize without `map`. Your use of `map` without a return value is an anti-pattern, check the [MDN docs on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#when_not_to_use_map).

Comment: @Morgan, it seems that the async map returns at the first await encounter even though it its not explicitly stated. How would you write a for loop that runs faster than map when you don't care about order between iterations (can run in parallel) but you do care about which order promises finish inside an interation (need to run concurrently), which seems to be what map does.

Comment: @MuriloBotelho you should ask about optimizing with a `for` loop in another SO question. All I'm pointing out is that MDN is calling your use of `map` a *definite anti-pattern*, which I happen to agree with.

Comment: @Morgan `const promises = array.map(async (item) => { … }` has a return value (it is an async function), which is a Promise (Or would you consider `const promises = array.map((item) => { return new Promise(…) }` an anti-pattern?) And the newly generated array returned by `map` that contains now the Promises is used with `Promise.all(promises);`. So there is no anti-pattern with the `.map` here. However `Promise.all(promises);` by itself doesn't do anything and is wrong.

Comment: @Morgan [MDN: async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) `Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.`

Comment: @t.niese Precisely, it is the implicit return that makes it an anti-pattern. Use `map` this way if makes you happy, I see anti-patterns in use all the time.

Comment: @Morgan  `it is the implicit return that makes it an anti-pattern` No. You convert the contents of `array` into an array of Promises, which you then later could use to wait for all Promises to resolve using `Promise.all` that is by no means an anti-pattern. Having `.map(async () => { return true; })` would not return `true` in the `map` callback it would still implicitly return a Promise. No matter what you write in the `async` function it will always return a `Promise`.

Comment: @t.niese the example is returning promises that wrap `undefined`. If you think this is a valid use of `map` maybe you should open a PR with MDN docs explaining why they are wrong?

Comment: @Morgan the statement of MDN is not wrong. It is just your interpretation of it. The statement is `… You shouldn't be using map if: you're not using the array it returns; and/or you're not returning a value from the callback.`  So about the `you're not returning a value from the callback.`: the `async` function returns a Promise, so this does not violate that one. About the `you're not using the array it returns`: if you write `await Promise.all(async() => {…})` you use it to wait for all Promises in the list to resolve or for one to reject. So also this one does not violate it.

Comment: @Morgan in the given case the `Promise.all(promises);` makes it an anti-pattern. Because it doesn't really use it, but the `array.map(async (item) => { })`  by itself not returning anything from the `async` function does not, because the `async` function does return a Promise, which further can be used to correctly wait for all tasks to finish.

Comment: @t.niese _implicitly_ returning a promise that wraps `undefined` while also not using the return value other than to await the promises, which the example does, definitely describes `You shouldn't be using map if: you're not using the array it returns; and/or you're not returning a value from the callback.`. Maybe open a PR asking MDN to say using implicit returns from `async` functions is not an anti-pattern?

Comment: @Morgan again the there is no need for a PR. If you have this simplified code a fetch and insert to db: `let urls = […]; await db.beginTransaction() try { await Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {let data = await (await fetch(url)).json(); await db.insert(data);})  await db.commitTransaction(); } catch (err) { await db.rollback(); }` then your clearly use the returned Promises, to wait for all requests to be done and inserted into to the database and commit the transaction, or to rollback if one of the fetch or insert failed. So you return something from the callback and you use it.

Comment: @t.niese I don't see any of that code in the original example though. You can add all the code you want in your comments, but there is **no** convincing me that the use of `map` in the original example is not an anti-pattern. It clearly is an anti-pattern.

`It is easier to fool people than to convince them they have been fooled` - Mark Twain.

Comment: @Morgan If you read my comment again you will see that I say that `Promise.all(promises);` makes it wrong, because it does not really use it. But `Your use of map without a return value is an anti-pattern` and `it is the implicit return that makes it an anti-pattern.` is an invalid statement. It is not the `array.map(async() => {})` where nothing is returned from `async` that makes it an anti-pattern it is the `Promise.all(promises);` which actually does not really use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `.map` will launch the callback for each array element *synchronously*. Those callbacks are asynchronous, and so each execution of it will *return* when having evaluated the first `await` expression. So you get a bunch of suspended executions which each will only continue later from a job in the promise job queue (asynchronously).

Note that your call of `Promise.all` will execute after all *"start"* outputs, but it actually isn't doing anything useful, as you don't do anything with the promise that it returns.

Each `.map` callback will synchronously launch the first HTTP request with the intended `user.id` (which is the current item from the array), but that URL evaluation is the last synchronous code that executes. By the time the `await`-ed promises resolve, `user.id` will have the value of the last item in the array.

Asynchronously, each of the callback executions will then resume. At that time `user.id` already has the value of the last item in the array. These resumed executions will thus launch their second HTTP request with the last `id` (3). If your intention was that those second requests would use the *same* `id` as the one that preceded it in the code, then you'd have to pass `item` as URL query, not `item.id`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know why does each execution return when having evaluated the first await expression? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the map needs to return something and it somehow returns the first asynchronous call? How does it manage to still keep track of the other ones?

Comment: This is the behaviour of `await`. It makes the `async` function return a promise. Further execution of the `async` function will be triggered when the promise, on which the `await` is applied, resolves. This is not specific to the `.map` context you have here; it always works like that with `await`.

Comment: By running this code with map and a traditional for loop, I see that using map runs it much faster, even though each await actually waits for the promise to resolve. What is the difference then? It seems that, even though both ways you are waiting for each promise to finish, using map does run each loop iteration in parallel while the for loop runs each one after the other and actually waits all promises from previous iteration to finish running.

Comment: `map` does not wait. It just calls the first function, and when it returns (remember: when `await` is encountered), it immediately calls the next, ...etc. A `for` loop does not have a callback function, so any `await` in a `for` loop makes the function (in which the `await` is positioned .... which is the *same* function the `for` loop is in) return! Therefore the `for` loop will only do its next iteration when the awaited promise resolves and the function resumes.